# CSS (bootstrap) line after blue border (with example)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning css have the current code.

```css
.nav-item {
  padding-left: 2rem !important;
}

.gutterwire-main-content {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.gw_content_title {
  padding: 7px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
  -o-transition: background-color .3s;
  transition: background-color .3s;
  font-family: CNN, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Utkal, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 1.0666666667rem;
  line-height: 1.375;
}

.gw_content_title:after {
  background-color: #3061f3;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  height: .25rem;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
  width: 1rem;
}

.gw--extra-small {
  border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}

.lastest-gutters li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 2rem !important;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="lastest-gutters col-sm-6 col-md-3">
  <h2 class="gw_content_title">Lastest news</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <article style="border:1px solid red; margin-bottom:20px">
        ddddddd
      </article>

      <article style="border:1px solid red; margin-bottom:20px">
        ddddddd
      </article>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jhqwbghp/1/

So far I've gotten the blue bar I want, but I can't add the line above the article to make it look like this:

[image]

How would I do this to match the picture I provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would separate each article into its own `li`. You can then apply a `border-top` to each `li` which will give you the separation lines and then you can use `first-child` to apply a pseudo element to the first list item, which will give you the blue underline. You could do something like this:

```css
.nav-item{
  padding-left: 2rem !important;
}

.gutterwire-main-content {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.gw_content_title {
  padding: 7px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
  -o-transition: background-color .3s;
  transition: background-color .3s;
  font-family: CNN,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,Utkal,sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 1.0666666667rem;
  line-height: 1.375;
}

.gw--extra-small {
  border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}

.latest-gutters ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0 0 0 7px;
}

.latest-gutters li {
  list-style: none;
  padding:1rem 0;
  border-top:1px solid #d9d9d9;
  position:relative;
}
  .latest-gutters li:first-child:before {
    background-color: #3061f3;
    top:-.25rem;
    content: "";
    height: .25rem;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
    width: 1rem;
  }
```

```html
<div class="latest-gutters col-sm-6 col-md-3">
  <h2 class="gw_content_title">Latest news</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <article>ddddddd</article>
    </li>
    <li>
      <article>ddddddd</article>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Note that I fixed some spelling errors in both your HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0):

you could use a hr and then style the hr with css:

```html
  

<hr>

<p>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

<hr>

<p>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

<hr>

<p>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
```

or us a css border top:

```css
.newsBox {
  border-bottom : 4px solid #476DA5;
  width: 50px;
}

.box {
  border-top : solid 1px #333333;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="newsBox">
  <h2>News</h2>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <p>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed      do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore        magna aliqua.</p>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <p>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed      do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore        magna aliqua.</p>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <p>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed      do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore        magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
```

CSS rule to `.gw_content_title` element.

```css
  .nav-item{
      padding-left: 2rem !important;
      }

      .gutterwire-main-content {
          margin-top: 1rem;
      }

      .gw_content_title {
          padding: 7px;
          position: relative;
          -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
          -o-transition: background-color .3s;
          transition: background-color .3s;
          font-family: CNN,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,Utkal,sans-serif;
          font-weight: 700;
          -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
          font-size: 16px;
          font-size: 1.0666666667rem;
          line-height: 1.375;
          border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; /* Right here! */
       }

      .gw_content_title:after {
          background-color: #3061f3;
          bottom: 0;
          content: "";
          height: .25rem;
          left: 0;
          position: absolute;
          -webkit-transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
          -o-transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
          transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
          width: 1rem;
       }

       .gw--extra-small {
          border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
       }

       .lastest-gutters li{
         list-style: none;
         margin-bottom: 2rem !important;
         padding: 0;
       }
```

```html
<div class="lastest-gutters col-sm-6 col-md-3">
          <h2 class="gw_content_title">Lastest news</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <article style="border:1px solid red; margin-bottom:20px">
                ddddddd
              </article>
              
              <article style="border:1px solid red; margin-bottom:20px">
                ddddddd
              </article>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```